# How to solve a Markov transition matrix using Mathematica?

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I need some help in working out how to solve this problem.

I have a transition matrix of size $4\times4$ at time $t=0$ - call it $A$

I also have another transition matrix at time $t= 10$ - call it $B$

What I don't know is the behaviour of the matrix between $t=0$ and $ t=10$. I think the matrix $A$ is raised to the power of some value such that by time $t=10$, it equals $B$.

Assuming discrete steps, is there a way to solve this - i.e. What are the matrices at times $t=1, t=2, t=3....t=9$ such that at $t=10$ it equals $B$

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Are the transition matrices changing?

Comment: yes, i think they would over time

Comment: Take a look at `MatrixPower`.  Also, please include your actual matrices in the question.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If the transition matrix is changing over time, you must define how it changes.  Anyway A and B are not independent, if A is given at any time, then B is given.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

If it's the same matrix $A$ each time step, you can use `MatrixPower` to find the 10th root of $B$.

```
b = {{0.6, 0.2, 0.3, 0.05}, {0.1, 0.7, 0.05, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.05, 0.6, 0.05}, {0.2, 0.05, 0.05, 0.8}};
a = MatrixPower[b, 1/10]
(* {{0.944042, 0.028917, 0.0482863, 0.0039194}, {0.0130071, 0.962815, 
  0.00433658, 0.0126691}, {0.015021, 0.00533637, 0.946473, 
  0.00635045}, {0.0279295, 0.00293193, 0.000903775, 0.977061}} *)
```

All of the intermediate steps:

```
Do[Print["t=", t, " ", MatrixPower[a, t] // MatrixForm], {t, 1, 10}]
```

[image]